# Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value, but is set to auto_increment

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot

So I'm trying to build a meal planner program, but when I try to submit a username it gives me the error displayed in the title. I've tried adding additional mapping to my classes, I created a new repo for the User class, and I'm not sure why the program isn't auto-incrementing the user_ID value like it should.

Here is my offending mySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_table` (
  `user_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Here is the User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_table")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_ID")
    private int userID;

    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String userName;

    public User() {
        super();

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public User(int userID, String userName) {
        super();
        this.userID = userID;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }
    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "User [userID=" + userID + ", userName=" + userName + "]";
    }
}
```

The repo the user class attaches to:

```
@Repository
public interface MealPlannerRepositoryUser extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

And the relevant methods from my controller class:

```
    @Autowired
    MealPlannerRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    MealPlannerRepositoryUser userRepo;

    @GetMapping("/inputUser")
    public String addNewUser(Model model) {
        User u = new User();
        Meal m = new Meal();
        model.addAttribute("newUser", u);
        model.addAttribute("newMeal", m);
        return "inputUser";
    }

    @PostMapping("/inputUser")
    public String addNewUser(@ModelAttribute User u, Meal m, Model model) {
        userRepo.save(u);
        repo.save(m);
        model.addAttribute("newUser", repo.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("newMeal", repo.findAll());
        return "results";
    }
```

I must be missing something somewhere, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Did you find the answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is case sensitive or not but the annotation @Column('user_ID') in the User class doesn't match with the column name 'user_id' in your SQL query.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's capitalized or not, sadly. SQL is case insensitive so it should read either way.

Comment: The queries can be case insensitive but the ORM framework can be case sensitive. Try matching the case in your entity class and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

in the entity class user_ID doesn't match with column name user_id, change in entity class user_id